# IIS url rewrite | How to remove directory and extension?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-8

I have been struggling with the following for quite some time now:

Default url:

```
examplesite.com/folder/about.cshtml
```

Desired url:

```
examplesite.com/about
```

Basically I want to accomplish two things:

- 1 Remove the file extension with realtively compact code.
- 2 Remove the folder that houses the about page.

I have found some uncommon rules to achieve all the above, but they mostly contain a lot of redundant code that crashes my site when I test it with IIS 8.0.

So I was hoping someone could share a rule that is compact and fits my needs. Or seperate rules with the same outcome.

Every contribution is much appreciated :)

Comment: IIRC with Razor you can drop the `.cshtml` anyhow - http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/creating-readable-urls-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites

Answer (score 6):

I'm not certain I entirely understand your needs, but here's something that's at least close. It strips out the first folder and file extension (so `examplesite.com/folder/about.cshtml` becomes `examplesite.com/about` and `examplesite.com/folder/help/about.cshtml` becomes `examplesite.com/help/about`). If you wanted to strip **all** folders then just remove the `?`.

```
<rule name="Remove Directory and Extension">
    <match url="^(.*?)/(.*)\.cshtml$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

**Update:**

Ok, I think what you want is a combination of two rules then:

```
<rules>
  <rule name="Redirect requests to friendly URLs">
    <match url="^(.*?)/(.*)\.cshtml$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Rewrite friendly URLs to phsyical paths">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="folder/{R:0}.cshtml" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

The first rule makes sure that all requests are to friendly URLs. The second takes the friendly URL and rewrites it to your physical path, where the physical path is `folder/[FRIENDLY_PATH].cshtml`.

Comment: It makes the page effected by the rewrite inaccessible.

Comment: Sorry, what's the end goal? Do you want users that go to `examplesite.com/about` and be served `examplesite.com/folder/about.cshtml`?

Comment: Yes, though i'd like to have a persistent url, so `examplesite.com/folder/about.cshtml` shouldn't ever show in the urlbar like that.